# OSX C++ Eclipse crashes a lot, what can I do?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm running a clean installation (no additional plugins) of C++ Eclipse Indigo (build id 20110615-0604) on a 2011 Macbook Pro running OSX (10.6.8, 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7, 4GB 1333Mhz DDR3 memory, 302/500GB free HD space). It crashes a lot, even though my projects are fairly small at the moment (<5000 lines).

There doesn't seem to be an obvious pattern to the crashes, although it does seem to occur sometimes when the autocomplete is attempting to do something (yes, I wait on the beachball for a while before giving up).

Is the C++ version of Eclipse known to be unstable on OSX? Are there common solutions to this?

Comment: The preferred development environment on Mac OS for native languages usually is Xcode. Are you using Eclipse out of habit, or for a specific reason?

Comment: how about changing to Komodo Edit? i grew tired of the crashes and absurd memory comsumption of eclipse and changed to another ide

Comment: I have a limited amount of time to devote to familiarizing myself with new IDEs (I'm already spending time switching from emacs as is) + I don't see myself developing exclusively for OSX in the future => I'd like to be more familiar with Eclipse as an IDE. Of course, if eclipse is known to be practically unusable on OSX, then I'd reconsider.

Comment: as an alternative you might consider Qt, it is fairly popular and has nice documentation. Qt runs nicely on Mac

Comment: @Aditya: does Qt include an *IDE* these days ?

Comment: I'm sorry I was talking about the Qt Creator to be specific.

Comment: NetBeans on Windows is pretty solid.  It can also run on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me using eclipse 64-bit. Switching to the 32-bit solved the problem.

Comment: Moving over to 32 bit eclipse worked a treat for me (so far).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Eclipse allowed memory. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

This may solve your issues.